# Nokogiri installed but not found when using nanoc

Tags: bundler, nokogiri, rbenv, nanoc

I'm having a problem with a project using bundler and rbenv:

I'm in my projects root dir and enter

```
bundle install
```

which installs all bundles according to my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'
gem 'nanoc', '~> 3.2.4'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.1.15'
gem 'coderay', '~> 1.0.5'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.4.4'
gem 'yajl-ruby', '~> 0.8.2'
gem 'pygmentize', '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'coderay', '~> 1.0.5'
gem 'fssm', '~>0.2.9'
gem 'coderay_bash', '~>1.0.2'
gem 'kramdown', '~> 0.13.2'
gem 'htmlentities', '~> 4.3.1'
```

This also claims to install nokogiri. But whenever I run

```
nanoc compile
```

I get an error message saying:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri
Try installing the 'nokogiri' gem (`gem install nokogiri`) and then re-running the command.
```

I already tried uninstalling the gem with `gem uninstall nokogiri` and running the whole thing again, but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite strange. From what I can tell, your setup looks correct. I don’t see a solution immediately, but perhaps removing the Gemfile.lock and re-running “bundle install” may do the trick.

**Update:** Do you have multiple nanoc versions installed? It might be that the nanoc version that you are using (because it is first in $PATH) is not the one installed by the `gem` from rbenv. Does switching to system ruby, uninstalling the nanoc gem, and then switching back to your rbenv ruby fix nanoc?

Comment: Did not work so far. But I tried `rbenv exec nanoc compile` after reinstalling the gems which seems to work now...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with compiling the developer.github nonoc pages. My problem was that I changed the ruby version in the *Gemfile*. Then yajl was not found when I did `nanoc compile`. My solution to problem was to remove all versions specified after dependencies in the *Gemfile* and then do:

```
bundle update
```

Whith the new versions of yajl, nokogiri etc I was able to run `nanoc compile` without problems.